# How update title bar on terminator?

Tags: ssh, terminal, gnome-terminator

I have installed Terminator in my linux Mint on xfce. When I open it, the title bar is correct:

[image]

but, when I log into a remote server via ssh, the title bar doesn't update:

[image]

How can I fix the title?

Please note that I work with over 1k servers and it's not doable modifying anything server-side.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash`, add to `$HOME/.bashrc` of your server the next line:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="printf \"\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007\" \"${USER}\" \"${HOSTNAME%%.*}\" \"${PWD/#$HOME/~}\""
```

Comment: That's not doable, as I work with over 1k servers...

Comment: Wow, that a new and interesting fact! I suggest  updating the question, so new answers can take it into account.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a client-side script that sets the title of the target and does the ssh, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '\033]0;%s\007' "$*"
ssh "$@"
printf '\033]0;%s\007' "(local machine)"
```